# Theming a EntityListBuilder.php table using drupal/examples/content_entity_example as base

Tags: theming, entities, 9

Any idea how I could to use my own custom module twig file to theme my table?

I'm using drupal/examples -> content_entity_example as a starting point:

in content_entity_example.module implementing hook_theme I would like to return all fields like:

```php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains Drupal\content_entity_example\content_entity_example.module.
 */

/**
 * @defgroup content_entity_example Example: Content Entity
 * @ingroup examples
 * @{
 * Implement a content entity.
 *
 * This module demonstrates implementing a content entity.
 *
 * Entity API is the API that stores pieces of content and configuration for
 * Drupal core. For instance, if you've encountered node content types, you've
 * encountered entities of type 'node.'
 *
 * This example implements the Entity API so that we have an entity type usable
 * by the user which you might think of as specialized nodes, but which are
 * different from nodes. These entities are called Contact, and are known
 * internally by the machine name content_entity_example_contact.
 *
 * Contact is a fieldable content entity used to hold structured information
 * without the overhead of using a node content type. 'Fieldable' means you can
 * attach fields to it, like you can with nodes. It is defined programmatically
 * (completely in code). We will show the main techniques to handle and expose
 * the contents of this entity type.
 *
 * The Contact entity will demonstrate the main tasks for an entity:
 * - define
 * - save
 * - load
 * - view
 * - edit
 * - delete
 * - control access
 *
 * Where ever possible, we use the amazing tools built into D8 natively.
 *
 * @see Drupal\content_entity_example\Entity\Contact
 * @see config_entity_example
 * }
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_theme(). Register a module or theme's theme implementations.
 */

function content_entity_example_theme() {
  return [
    'content_entity_example_table' => [
      'variables' => [
        'header' => NULL,
        'rows' => NULL,
        'footer' => NULL,
        'attributes' => [],
        'caption' => NULL,
        'colgroups' => [],
        'sticky' => FALSE,
        'responsive' => TRUE,
        'empty' => ''
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

And in src/Entity/Controller/ContactListBuilder.php I would like to pickup my template ( '#template' ...)

So I would like to tell render() to user my template

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * We override ::render() so that we can add our own content above the table.
   * parent::render() is where EntityListBuilder creates the table using our
   * buildHeader() and buildRow() implementations.
   */
  public function render() {
    $build['description'] = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Content Entity Example implements a Contacts model. These contacts are fieldable entities. You can manage the fields on the <a href="@adminlink">Contacts admin page</a>.', [
        '@adminlink' => $this->urlGenerator->generateFromRoute('content_entity_example.contact_settings'),
      ]),
    ];
    $build['table'] = parent::render();

// TODO add template reference

    return $build;
  }
```

and as such use my template file in /templates/content-entity-example.html.twig
which is going to be changed in a later phase. (just need to get it loaded)

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a table.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the <table> tag.
 * - caption: A localized string for the <caption> tag.
 * - colgroups: Column groups. Each group contains the following properties:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the <col> tag.
 *     Note: Drupal currently supports only one table header row, see
 *     https://www.drupal.org/node/893530 and
 *     http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7#comment-5109.
 * - header: Table header cells. Each cell contains the following properties:
 *   - tag: The HTML tag name to use; either 'th' or 'td'.
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the tag.
 *   - content: A localized string for the title of the column.
 *   - field: Field name (required for column sorting).
 *   - sort: Default sort order for this column ("asc" or "desc").
 * - sticky: A flag indicating whether to use a "sticky" table header.
 * - rows: Table rows. Each row contains the following properties:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes to apply to the <tr> tag.
 *   - data: Table cells.
 *   - no_striping: A flag indicating that the row should receive no
 *     'even / odd' styling. Defaults to FALSE.
 *   - cells: Table cells of the row. Each cell contains the following keys:
 *     - tag: The HTML tag name to use; either 'th' or 'td'.
 *     - attributes: Any HTML attributes, such as "colspan", to apply to the
 *       table cell.
 *     - content: The string to display in the table cell.
 *     - active_table_sort: A boolean indicating whether the cell is the active
         table sort.
 * - footer: Table footer rows, in the same format as the rows variable.
 * - empty: The message to display in an extra row if table does not have
 *   any rows.
 * - no_striping: A boolean indicating that the row should receive no striping.
 * - header_columns: The number of columns in the header.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_table()
 */
#}
<table{{ attributes }}>
  {% if caption %}
    <caption>{{ caption }}</caption>
  {% endif %}

  {% for colgroup in colgroups %}
    {% if colgroup.cols %}
      <colgroup{{ colgroup.attributes }}>
        {% for col in colgroup.cols %}
          <col{{ col.attributes }} />
        {% endfor %}
      </colgroup>
    {% else %}
      <colgroup{{ colgroup.attributes }} />
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if header %}
    <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for cell in header %}
      {%
        set cell_classes = [
        cell.active_table_sort ? 'is-active',
      ]
      %}
      <{{ cell.tag }}{{ cell.attributes.addClass(cell_classes) }}>
      {{- cell.content -}}
    </{{ cell.tag }}>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </thead>
  {% endif %}

  {% if rows %}
    <tbody>
    {% for row in rows %}
      {%
        set row_classes = [
        not no_striping ? cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0),
      ]
      %}
    <tr{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
      {% for cell in row.cells %}
        <{{ cell.tag }}{{ cell.attributes }}>
        {{- cell.content -}}
        </{{ cell.tag }}>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  {% elseif empty %}
    <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td colspan="{{ header_columns }}" class="empty message">{{ empty }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  {% endif %}
  {% if footer %}
    <tfoot>
    {% for row in footer %}
    <tr{{ row.attributes }}>
      {% for cell in row.cells %}
        <{{ cell.tag }}{{ cell.attributes }}>
        {{- cell.content -}}
        </{{ cell.tag }}>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tfoot>
  {% endif %}
</table>
```

content_entity_example works great but I can't load my own template.

Comment: From the code isn't clear which method is `parent::render()` calling, since we don't know which is the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as setting the `#theme` on the table that `parent::render()` returns:

```
$build = parent::render();
$build['table']['#theme'] = 'content_entity_example_table';
```

Comment: thanks, my twig file gets called, but if I do {{ kint(header) }} in my custom twig,  it's empty.
If I disable my theme() function, the default drupal theme gets called which has a header. so I suppose my custom theme() function isn't properly configured. I can't seem to find the docs for correct settings.

Comment: `$build['table']['#theme'] = 'table__content_entity_example';` which is defined in theme() as `'base hook' => 'table'`.